# InvalidOperationException while consuming WCF web service in Windows Phone 7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, invalidoperationexception

I created a simple WCF web service(following this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/11/getting-started-building-a-wcf-web-service.aspx), because I don't want to use default namespace, so I defined my own namespace in ServiceContract, DataContract, ServiceBehavior and web.config shown in http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2008/07/kill-tempuri-in-wcf-services.html

When I consume this WCF web service, I keep getting InvlidOperationException in the declaration: 
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ABCWcfService.IABCWcfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I located the reason was due to the endpoint change I made in the web.config file for customized namespace. As long as I include the endpoint, it will have this exception in my client code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ABCWcfService.ABCWcfServiceBehavior" name="ABCWcfService.SkycityWcfService">
        <endpoint bindingNamespace="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ABCWcfService.IABCWcfService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>      
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ABCWcfService.ABCWcfServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the client code, it is simple:

```
ABCWcfServiceClient abcWcfServiceClient = new ABCWcfServiceClient();
abcWcfServiceClient.GetWhatsOnDataAsync();
abcWcfServiceClient.GetWhatsOnDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(ABCWcfServiceClient_GetWDataCompleted);
```

I got this exception every time it goes into 1st line.

If I disable the endpoint section in web.config file, it is fine.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Could it be that the problem is localhost? Have you deployed the webservice somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I deployed in IIS. I don't think the local host really cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wsHttpBinding is not supported by windows phone. Use basicHttpBinding instead...

See http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=281

Comment: Thank you. I found that if I change the endpoint as: <endpoint bindingNamespace="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService" address="http://desktop/ABCWcfService/ABCWcfService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ABCWcfService.IABCWcfService"></endpoint>, it works, so "desktop" is my computer name in IIS and without the identity section. Any reason why? It seems I have to use desktop, can not use localhost in the address.